# JPA / Hibernate Query execution time too high

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I'm working with `Spring Data 4.3.7` with the `Hibernate` vendor. My DB is `MySQL 5.2.5`. I have a query with 3 cross join (developed in JPQL), the query is called thousands of times. As the number of calls increases, its average operating time increases. Why does his time grow as a function of the number of invocations?
Can you help me please?

This is the query:

```
select distinct attrrelaen3_.atwrt as col_0_0_, attrrelaen3_.msehi as col_1_0_,
from A articolian0_ cross join B catalogore1_ cross join C templateen2_ cross join D attrrelaen3_
 where articolian0_.cod_mat='XXXX' and 
 catalogore1_.pk_document=articolian0_.pk_document and 
 catalogore1_.begda<=CURRENT_DATE and 
 catalogore1_.endda>=CURRENT_DATE and (catalogore1_.pk_document_chld like 'ZCS%') 
 and templateen2_.template=catalogore1_.zzcattemplate and templateen2_.caratt=attrrelaen3_.atinn 
 and attrrelaen3_.pk_oggetto=articolian0_.cod_mat and attrrelaen3_.begda<=CURRENT_DATE 
 and attrrelaen3_.endda>=CURRENT_DATE 
 order by templateen2_.msehi  ASC
```

Comment: The answer to your question is probably that the average execution time is unreliable for a small number of samples. Could you provide more details (the query, the data model etc.)?

Comment: I added the query in question. Thanks

Comment: Is this in a single Hibernate Session? If so your session might gather more and more entities, making every lookup slower and slower.

Comment: Yes, there is one only transaction. There are some repository and entity. The repository and service are @Transactional. Could I Use Multiple Transactions?

Answer (score 0):

For starters - run the exact same query by hand from CLI or SQL workbench and compare execution times. If they are similar - you know your query is either badly optimised or there is a lack of some indexes. You will have to run `explain query` to get details on that.

All in all you will know for sure that problem lies in ORM or in DB itself.

Comment: The query is in long iteration. For the first thousands of iterations the times are good, with time they become worse. In  SQL workbench the query does not seem to have any problems.